# Troubles with Oracle SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I want to extract the following requirements :

- Job Title.
- Number of Users.

Tables and sample data:

```
     **Job_Applied**             **Jobs_posted**

Job_id  Empl_id  User_id   | Job_id  Empl_id  Job_Title
------------------------     --------------------------
  1        2        3      |     1       2       Android
  1        2        4      |     2       2        Web
  1        2        5      |     3       4       Java
  2        2        3      |
  2        2        3      |
  2        2        7      | 
  3        2        5      |
```

I have tried:

```
  Select count(User_id) as Users , Job_Title 
  from Jobs_posted 
  inner join Jobs_Applied on Jobs_posted.job_id = Jobs_Applied.job_id.
```

I get number of users that applied on job. How can I get job_title with zero number of users. I have also tried left join. Kindly help.

Comment: You title has `Oracle SQL` and you tagged `mysql`. So, which of the two DBMS are you using, Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: What are the tables's primary keys? What role does `empl_id` play? Is this column important for the query or can we safely ignore it?

Comment: The combination `(Job_id, Empl_id, User_id) = (2, 2, 3)` occurs twice in `Job_Applied`. Do you want this user count twice for the job accordingly or just once?

Comment: I am downvoting the request. As my questions above show, it is incomplete, and the OP hasn't answered any of the questions. This makes the request rather worthless for any other reader than the OP himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to group by `Job_Title`

```
Select count(distinct User_id) as Users , p.Job_Title 
  from Jobs_posted p
  left join Jobs_Applied a 
    on p.job_id = a.job_id and p.Empl_id = a.Empl_id  
 group by p.Job_Title
```

Comment: Thank you. But if jobs_applied table is empty I want to show job_title with number of user = 0.

Comment: @JahanzebAwan you're welcome, you need to use left join then. Because jobs_applied is on the right side. If it was on the left side you would need to use a right join.

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
 Select count(a.User_id) as Users , p.Job_Title 
    from Jobs_posted p
    left join Jobs_Applied a 
      on p.job_id = a.job_id and p.Empl_id=a.Empl_id
   group by p.Job_Title
```